# Line breaks between variables in PHP

Tags: php, whitespace, spaces

I have a variable like this in foreach

```
$variable=$variable1."               ".$variable2;
```

Output is

```
apple                   fruit
tomato                   fruit
pineapple                   fruit
```

How I want is

```
    apple                   fruit
    tomato                  fruit
    pineapple               fruit
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Calculate the number of required spaces by yourself. Use the length of the first text.

Comment: http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: Do you require tabulation `\t` ?

Comment: why cant you use table/div/span instead of spaces?

Comment: use an html table!

Comment: You could probably also use [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). I doubt that the OP's result is in a HTML page, since there are multiple spaces in the result. HTML would only show one space, regardless how many you put in after each other, so using HTML tables might not be appropriate.

Comment: Use a table for tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\t" is not a viable option but @Magnus Eriksson gave good answer:

`echo "\t".$var1."\t".$var2.PHP_EOL`:

```
   apple   fruit
   tomato   fruit
   pineapple   fruit
```

`echo ' '.str_pad($var1,20," ").$var2.PHP_EOL`:

```
  apple               fruit
  tomato              fruit
  pineapple           fruit
```